# Difference between VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT and VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT

Tags: vulkan

If I have a transfer that I need completed before the shaders read the data, do I need to use SHADER_READ bit or MEMORY_READ bit or both? I mean ... reading from index buffer, vertex input, storage buffer, uniform, sampled images, etc. Does the same go for compute shaders?

Comment: "*index buffer, vertex input, storage buffer, uniform, sampled images*" Not all of those are shaders reading data. Which is what "shader read" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT` includes any memory read access. It is a superset of `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT`, which includes only the specified read accesses (per [non-extended Vulkan 1.0 specification](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkAccessFlagBits)):

> `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` specifies read access to a *uniform texel buffer*, *sampled image*, *storage buffer*, *physical storage buffer*, *shader binding table*, *storage texel buffer*, or *storage image* in any shader pipeline stage.

Note the lack of mention of reading from vertex and index buffer.

Both these access flag bits are usable even with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT`.

Comment: VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT is a superset of VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT, meaning it covers extra stuff the other doesn't? What does it cover in addition?

Comment: @Zebrafish Every memory access. I.e. basically bitwise-or of all the other access bits (including likely any future ones).